# subword-mode in minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer, subword-mode

I use subword-mode when I'm editing Python and C++ code, and it's jarring when deleting a word backwards/forwards (Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+Delete) works one way in the source code buffer and a different way when I'm in the minibuffer. Is there a way to make it consistent? I've never tried having a minor mode active in a minibuffer before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable the subword mode in the minibuffer by adding the below to your emacs init.

```el
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'subword-mode)
```

The same applies for any hook and minor mode.

- [Emacs manual - Minibuffer Misc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Misc.html)